# Returning array address from function did not work

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I have a C program in which the user enters sets of grades. Everything works correctly. The GPA is calculated correctly, etc. However, when the numbers are printed back out, both pointers in the Student structs point to the same address for some reason, leading both students to display the grades of the second when the information is printed out. The rest of the information is correct, it's only the grades that are identical.

The only thing I can think of is that the second initialization of the grades array overwrites the first. I don't understand why this happens or how to fix it.

The following is sample IO of the program:

```
Enter the number of students:> 2
Enter the number of grades to track:> 3

There are 2 students.
There are 3 grades.

Enter information for student:
        Enter SID:> 101
        Enter last name:> Enright
        Enter first name:> Reed
        Enter grades (separated by space):> 70.1 60 92

Enter information for student:
        Enter SID:> 123
        Enter last name:> Claire
        Enter first name:> Heidi
        Enter grades (separated by space):> 82.5 96.1 89.0

Student ID #101:
        Name:   Reed Enright
        Grades: 82.5 96.1 89.0
        GPA:    74.03
Student ID #123:
        Name:   Heidi Claire
        Grades: 82.5 96.1 89.0
        GPA:    89.20
```

and this is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NAME_SIZE 25

typedef struct {
        int sid;
        char last_name[NAME_SIZE];
        char first_name[NAME_SIZE];
        float *grades;
        float gpa;
} Student;

// function prototypes

// get student information
Student prompt_student(int number_of_grades); 
// calculate the gpa based on the grades
float calculate_gpa(Student student, int number_of_grades); 
// prints all of the students
void print_all_students(Student students[], int number_of_students, int number_of_grades);

int main(){
        // initialise variables
        int number_of_students;
        int number_of_grades;

        // prompt for number of students
        printf("\nEnter the number of students:> ");
        scanf("%d", &number_of_students);
        // prompt for number of grades
        printf("Enter the number of grades to track:> ");
        scanf("%d", &number_of_grades);

        // confirm the above
        printf("\nThere are %d students. \nThere are %d grades.\n",
                        number_of_students, number_of_grades);

        // initialise student list
        Student students[number_of_students];
        // get and store student information
        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++){
                students[i] = prompt_student(number_of_grades);
        }

        // confirm the above
        print_all_students(students, number_of_students, number_of_grades);

        return 0;
}

Student prompt_student(int number_of_grades){
        // initialise student variable
        Student student;
        float grades[number_of_grades];
        printf("\nEnter information for student: \n");

        // prompt for student info
        printf("\tEnter SID:> ");
        scanf("%d", &(student.sid));

        printf("\tEnter last name:> ");
        scanf("%s", student.last_name);

        printf("\tEnter first name:> ");
        scanf("%s", student.first_name);

        printf("\tEnter grades (separated by space):> ");
        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_grades; i++){
                scanf("%f", &grades[i]);
        }
        student.grades = grades;

        student.gpa = calculate_gpa(student, number_of_grades);

        return student;
}

float calculate_gpa(Student student, int number_of_grades){
        float total = 0; // initialise variable for sum of grades
        // add all grades together
        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_grades; i++){
                total += student.grades[i];
        }
        // return average
        return total / number_of_grades;
}

void print_all_students(Student students[], int number_of_students, int number_of_grades){
        // loop through all students
        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++){
                // print student info
                printf("\nStudent ID #%d:", students[i].sid);
                printf("\n\tName:\t%s %s", students[i].first_name, students[i].last_name);
                printf("\n\tGrades:\t");
                for(int n = 0; n < number_of_grades; n++){
                        printf("%.1f ", students[i].grades[n]);
                }
                printf("\n\tGPA:\t%.2f", students[i].gpa);
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Consider the line `student.grades = grades;` in `prompt_student()`. Where are the grades located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that inside function `prompt_student` you declared local array

```
float grades[number_of_grades];
```

and the address of the first element of this local array is assigned to data member  `grades` of structure `Student`

```
student.grades = grades;
```

So this data member will always have the same address for each call of the function. And moreover the program has **undefined behaviour** because after exiting the function the local array is not alive. In general case it will be destroyed.

You must dynamically allocate an array and assign the address of the allocated array to data member `grades`.

For example

```
float *grades = malloc( number_of_grades * sizeof( float ) );
```

It is obvious that in main you should free the allocated memory when the corresponding object of the structure will not be used any more.

Answer (score 1):

Problem :

In your `prompt_student()` function, `grades` is a local variable (array). It goes out of scope when you return from the function. So,, you cannot assign the array (base address) to `student.grades` and use it after the function returns. If you use the pointer to access the memory, it  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution:

You need to allocate memory using dynamic memory allocation [`malloc()`/`calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to `student.grades` and *copy* the scanned values in there. Dynamically allocated memory lifetime is untill they are freed and they have a global scope. So, untill you're freeing the memory by calling `free()`, you can use the memory from outside the `prompt_student()` function also.

Answer (score 0):

You are using local ("on-stack") automatic variables that cease to exist when the scope they were declared in exits. This gives you undefined behavior.

You need to use dynamic memory allocation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a local object which is gone after a return.

```
Student prompt_student(int number_of_grades){
    // initialise student variable
    Student student;
    ...
    return student;
}
```

Instead, pass in a pointer to structure created outside the function scope

```
main() {
    Student student;

    prompt_student(&student, number_of_grades)

}


void prompt_student(Student *pStudent, int number_of_grades){
    // initialise student variable

    ...
    pStudent->grades = grades;
    ... etc ...
    return;

}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is not with the Student variable returned, it's with the grades array within that student. I specifically don't have a problem with this, as the sample output shows.

Comment: You have the same problem with the grades array.  You are creating local "stack" objects which disappear when you leave the function.